# How to bring created date from Cloud page to Data extension in Marketing Cloud Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need help with bringing a created date from Cloud page to Data extension when the record is created for the marketing cloud.  When I someone clicks on Submit button on Cloud Page, how we can send the date in Data extension put it under Created date?

[image: Data Extension]

[image: Cloud Page]

Comment: Never mind it is working now.. You have to set in the data extension. Create a new date field then click in "-". This will automatically set today's date when the record is created..

Answer (score 2):

In the data extension the form is submitted to:

1. You should set Created Date as a nullable field with type Date.
2. Set it’s default value to “current time”
3. Once the form gets submitted, time gets set to current time

Do observe it will be in UTC-6 time zone